# Use only part of an attribute when converting XML to CSV

Tags: python, csv, lxml, elementtree

I am new to Python and am attempting to process some XML into CSV files for later diff validation against the output from a database. The code I have below does a good job of taking the 'tct-id' attributes from the XML and outputting them in a nice column under the heading 'DocumentID', as I need for my validation.

However, the outputs from the database just come as numbers, whereas the outputs from this code include the version number of the XML ID; for example

```
tct-id="D-TW-0010054;3;"
```

where I need the **;3;** removed so I can validate properly.

This is the code I have; is there any way I can go about rewriting this so it will pre-process the XML snippets to remove that - like only take the first 12 characters from each attribute and write those to the CSV, for example?

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

xml_fname = 'example.xml'
csv_fname = 'output.csv'

fields = ['tct-id']

xml = etree.parse(xml_fname)

with open(xml_fname) as infile, open(csv_fname, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, delimiter=';', extrasaction="ignore")

    wtr = csv.writer(outfile)    
    wtr.writerow(["DocumentID"])

    for node in xml.xpath("//*[self::StringVariables or self::ElementVariables or self::PubInfo or self::Preface or self::DocHistory or self::Glossary or self::StatusInfo or self::Chapter]"):
        atts = node.attrib
        atts["elm_name"] = node.tag
        w.writerow(node.attrib)
```

All help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll only have one `;3;` type string to remove from the `tct-id`, you can use regular expressions

```
import re
tct_id="D-TW-0010054;3;"
to_rem=re.findall(r'(;.*;)',tct_id)[0]
tct_id=tct_id.replace(to_rem,'')
```

note i'm using `tct_id` instead of `tct-id` as python doesn't usually allow variables to be set like that

Comment: I didn't downvote you, though to be fair, this didn't work for me; I have multiple of these ;#; strings as my above code just produces a long list of these D-TW-00#####;#; strings. Also, I couldn't get your code to remove anything in the output either way

Comment: Well that is a different story. You have multiple `;#;` in each `tct-id`? or multiple `tct-id`'s? Because if you copy/paste my code into ipython it works fine

Comment: Multiple `tct-id`'s as that's what this code scrapes from the raw Manual XML

Comment: Ok so apply that re to each `tct-id`